# How to activate current tab in Jquery UI tabs?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

**Description:**
I am using `ASP.NET MVC 5`,`jquery` (latest version).
I am building an application where i would be using `jquery tabs` immensely.

I want to activate the `current tab` (after `Save->Reload`).
I am currently getting the `current tab` value using a **Tempdata**.I have no issue in getting value using `tempdata`. But i have to `hard code` values.(If submit request comes from `User` use `'1'`, If `Group` use `'2'` ,If `Module` use `'3'`).

**Question:**
How i can remove this hard coded approach.
I want to know what is the standard way to do this.

My Controller:

```
 TempData["TabId"] =1
```

Jquery:

```
   $(function () {
              $("#tabs").tabs();

              $("#tabs").tabs({
                active: '@TempData["TabId"]'
               });
       });

  function btn_Save_Module() {
        $(".container").on("click", "#btn-Save-Module", function () {

            $.ajax(
                           {
                               url: '@Url.Action("CreateEditModule")',
                               dataType: 'json',
                               data: $("#Form-Module").serialize(),
                               type: 'POST',
                               success: function (result) {

                                   if (result)
                                       alert("Successfully Saved");
                                   else
                                       alert("Save Failed");


                                   location.reload();   //*see this line*


                               },
                               error: function (xhr) {
                                   alert(xhr.statusText);
                               }
                           });

        });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

OK, if what I am looking at is a non-postback/ajax only save:

```
//Set active tab your .on("click" before the ajax call 
var active = $( "#tabs" ).tabs( "option", "active" );

/// Then in your ajax success method 
$("#tabs").tabs('select', active);
```

If there is a postback use a hidden field to store active and re-set upon postback